# how to submit the form using ENTER key

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to design a cluster layout with input field and submit button..everything works fine when i type the text and click enter button..but i want to use the ENTER key for this purpose...

i mean ONE ACTION IN TWO BUTTON(ENTER key and SUBMIT button)
below is what i have tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('editor').bind('keydown',function(event){
        var keyCode= (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode :
           (event.which ? event.which : event.charCode));
        if(keyCode==13){
            document.getElementById('update').click();
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

for the above code,no action on keypress and no error in the console
this is my entire code - https://pastebin.com/NbwEJQGX
Can anyone suggest me some way to solve this issue???

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

See this code for button clicks

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
    //do stuff for button click
});
```

Comment: He wants to submit it on enter when in input fields. this code is more than enough for his purpose.

Comment: i want  same action in two button(in submit and enter)

Comment: @prog you will need two events, one for button clicks and one for enter inside a input field.

Comment: thanks for your response.@ Deckerz..i thing this will work only with the enter key....let me try...

Comment: @prog yes it will only work with the enter key as that is what you asked for. See edit for button code. You may want to change the target to something more specific

Comment: @prog that is the code for it. We aren't here to debug for you. use `console.log()` to check. Also `.entr` which you are selecting doesnt exist in HTML

Answer (score 0):

```
    $("input").keyup(function(e){                            
       if(e.which == 13){ 
         $("#form").submit(); 
       } 
    });
```

Comment: thanks for your response ...i tries but nothing happened

Answer (score 0):

You can also call the function in the input

```
<input id="example" type="text" onkeypress="functionName(event, 0)" />
<input id="example" type="button" onclick="functionName(event, 1)" />

function functionName(e, n) {
if (e.keyCode == 13 || n == 1) {
   //do stuff
}
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response...i tried this....there is no change......let me retry...

Comment: perhaps the input is into the form tag so when you press ENTER key the form automatically submit, so if you want to control this action you should add onSubmit="return false;"  in the form. if you add the onSubmit, my solution might work... try it

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).keypress(function(e) {
          if(e.which == 13) {
               $( /*  Your form here   */).submit();
               return false;
          }
     });

     $(/*    Where to click     */).click(function(){
           $( /*  Your form here   */).submit();
               return false;
           });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your response @CristianS9...i think this will work only with the enter key and not with the submit button

Comment: i tried - https://pastebin.com/EUYCEZKv ...the output is the alert box...that there is no related words in the database....but the word is in the DB

Comment: I checked your code and is to messy: you have a lot of '$(document).ready ' and why u ask the function for the button? its already a submit button by default

Comment: thanks for your time...when i tried with $(document).ready(function(){ $("#editorForm").submit(function(){ e.preventDefault(); //rest of the code }); }); -there is no change when i click the submit button...thats why i tried that method

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add a class respective input field. then capture the event by the class as you may have multiple field where you want to submit the form after giving some value.

```
<input type="text" class="entr"/>
<input type="text" class="entr"/>

$('.entr').keypress(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('#editorForm').submit();
    }
});
```